# wj ignores the sym (ric) column in the join causing quotes for all stocks to be included in the window

Tags: kdb

When I use the window join (wj) as below, it does not behave as I would expect.
The key issue that it appears that the ric is not used in the join and so in the example below, for one stock (say 'COSC.SI), I get the prices for both 'COMF.SI and 'COSC.SI in the defined window. Could you advise what I am doing wrong? I note that I am forced to enter the columns in the wrong order to get the code to run without error - is there something wrong with my use of the 'r column (ric column)?

How can I get this function to produce the expected behaviour (prices grouped for each unique stock in the defined window)?

More broadly, as well as my implementation of wj, is there perhaps a better way of grouping prices in a time window around each price than the wj method I have used here?

Thanks and regards,

Simon

```
f:([]t:1998.02.01 1998.02.01 1998.02.02 1998.02.02 1998.02.03 1998.02.03 1998.02.04 1998.02.04 1998.02.05 1998.02.05;r:`COMF.SI`COSC.SI`COMF.SI`COSC.SI`COMF.SI`COSC.SI`COMF.SI`COSC.SI`COMF.SI`COSC.SI;price:0.7312963 0.835 0.8021131 0.7936364 0.7825 0.79 0.7583088 0.8 0.8322596 0.79)

/set the window
w:-3 0 +\:f[`t];
c:`r`t;
out: wj[w;c;f;(f;(::;`price))];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're joining on `` `r`t `` then your table must be sorted on `` `r`t `` to get correct results:

```
q)f:([]t:1998.02.01 1998.02.01 1998.02.02 1998.02.02 1998.02.03 1998.02.03 1998.02.04 1998.02.04 1998.02.05 1998.02.05;r:`COMF.SI`COSC.SI`COMF.SI`COSC.SI`COMF.SI`COSC.SI`COMF.SI`COSC.SI`COMF.SI`COSC.SI;price:0.7312963 0.835 0.8021131 0.7936364 0.7825 0.79 0.7583088 0.8 0.8322596 0.79)
q)f:`r`t xasc f;
q)w:-3 0 +\:f[`t];
q)c:`r`t;
q)show out:wj[w;c;f;(f;(::;`price))];
t          r       price
-------------------------------------------------------
1998.02.01 COMF.SI ,0.7312963
1998.02.02 COMF.SI 0.7312963 0.8021131
1998.02.03 COMF.SI 0.7312963 0.8021131 0.7825
1998.02.04 COMF.SI 0.7312963 0.8021131 0.7825 0.7583088
1998.02.05 COMF.SI 0.8021131 0.7825 0.7583088 0.8322596
1998.02.01 COSC.SI ,0.835
1998.02.02 COSC.SI 0.835 0.7936364
1998.02.03 COSC.SI 0.835 0.7936364 0.79
1998.02.04 COSC.SI 0.835 0.7936364 0.79 0.8
1998.02.05 COSC.SI 0.7936364 0.79 0.8 0.79
```

see: https://code.kx.com/q/ref/wj/

Comment: Thanks so much - appologies for the late response, I had thought I'd already accepted this.